# Is calling __new__ from a classmethod a pythonic way of doing?

Tags: python, new-operator, class-method

I want to build a class, that is handling and processing some data. So I want property to handle all the data processing silently when new data is passed And I want to overload init with classmethod, to have flexibility on parameters passed to instance creation. So I came up with the following solution :

```
class Cooper():
    def __init__(self):
        ...create all 'private' attributes 

    @classmethod
    def Dougie(cls,data,datatype):
         inst = cls.__new__(cls)
         setattr(inst,datatype,data)
         return inst

    @property
    def datatype1(self):
        return self._datatype1

    @datatype1.setter
    def datatype1(self,newdata):
        self._datatype1,self._datatype2,... = updatedata1(newdata)

    @property
    def datatype2(self):
        return self._datatype2

    @datatype2.setter
    def datatype2(self,newdata):
        self._datatype1,self._datatype2,... = updatedata2(newdata)

    ... to be continued...
```

Is this a pythonic way ? Or shoud I really create a metaclass (I get a little fir afraid there) ? What are the caveats ? Is there a better way ?

Comment: Why would you do this? Why not accept those values as parameters to `__init__` and set them there?

Comment: Why call `__new__` instead of simple `cls()`?

Comment: It's more convienient for me to handle it by multiple constructors rather than handling args and kwargs from outside

Comment: @WilfriedMaineult Sometimes it's convenient to have more than one constructor, but usually the additional constructors should just call `__init__()`.  In any case, calling `cls.__new__(cls)` instead of just `cls()` is pointless.  Can you give a more concrete example of what you are trying to achieve?  It's much easier and much more instructive to give advice for a concrete example.

Comment: @Sven_Marnach This object is the parent of several other childs, and several constructors are the most simple way I found to handle the object creation of the childs. But I'm a physicist, not a software developper, so, maybe i do stupid things...

Comment: @Ashwini Chaudhary But I don't want to call the __init__ of the 'Cooper'. this does long and unuseful calculation compare just to the __new__ method

Comment: @WilfriedMaineult I don't understand the use case.  Are you using "parent" and "child" in the sense of class inheritence, or in the sense of some tree datastructure?  Either way, I don't see why you would have constructors for children on the parent class.  (By the way, you @-mention did not reach my inbox due to the underscore you included, so I'm seeing your response only by chance.)

Comment: @SvenMarnach Thanks for the answer. Well, the complete thing is a set of fitting procedure, supposed to run 'live' Each time new data is passed, fit is updated (with the updatedata), so I need to reduce computation time. Depending on data passed to init, some old data is loaded if it is needed for the fit procedure (takes time also). Child inherits from parent methods and data structures, but operate on smaller parameter subset. I want then to initialize parent loading only the data I need. Last, I cannot move easily data imports to childs. That's the reason of the multiple instance creation

Comment: @WilfriedMaineult OK, I guess the only way to resolve this would be to look at your code, but I don't think I have time this week. As a general guideline, you should set _all_ attributes in `__init__()`, and call `cls(…)` from the other `classmethod` constructors (which will implicitly call `__init__(self, …)`). If there is additional initialisation work necessary in some cases, you can do this in standard methods that are called after the class has been created. And of course, if you think that your solution works better for you, by all means use it. …

Comment: … I'm just describing the usual conventions here, since you asked whether your code is idiomatic Python.

Comment: @SvenManach Thanks for the guidelines, I followed them. I hoped that my question was a little bit more general than this when I asked it, but, anyway... I got puzzled by several things I did not know before (there could be difference between attributes of instances and classes, and that metaclass are somehow designed to deal with that, what is a descriptor...) And as in the end I came up with a trick that worked for my case, I wanted to have the opinion of people, and eventually give the trick if someone gets in the problem : access a property while instantiating in a classmethod.